# Angularjs/Bootstrap how to switch focus to different tab on event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 tabs using the Bootstrap tabbable class. When I click a button, I want to have one of the tabs automatically get focus. So if I am on the first tab...click button...now I am on third tab.

I am sure there is a way to 'get' what tab is currently being viewed and when I click the button I can 'set' the view to a different tab. Trying to find out how in AngularJs

edit: Right now I have done angular.emelent("#name").trigger('click') inside my controller but that doesn't seem like the best idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable when click: `ng-click="tab = 1"` then use ng-show and ng-class to set the right tab to active class and display the right tab. But I recommand you AngularUI instead:
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: How AngularUI would help switching focus?

Comment: tabs[2].active = true